# Looping through ID to display output from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an id in table x representing a state in another table.

For instance.

Table x has a state id of 1 and that id of 1 in table z represents a state.

How would I loop through this in php and mysql to display the value of that id from table z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` to make sure it connects.

`SELECT z.id FROM x INNER JOIN z ON (x.id = z.x_id)`

Answer (score 0):

same solution, simplier notation is

```
select z.id
from tablex x,
     tablez z
where x.id = z.id
```